# why spinner view appears shrunk when called asynchronously in Android

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

## Background

When I fill a spinner using a resource array, things work just fine:

```
Spinner countryCodeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_code_spinner);
countryCodeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.country_codes_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

where country codes are read from a resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="country_codes_array">
        <item>971</item>
        <item>961</item>
        <item>628</item>
        <item>193</item>
        <item>477</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

output:
[image]

## Question

but when I fill up the spinner contents from an api call like so:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ..
    Spinner currencySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.currency_spinner);
    populateCurrency(currencySpinner);

private void populateCurrency(final Spinner spinner) {
    _currencies = new HashMap<String, String>();
    final Context context = this;
    // getting the contents of spinner from api call
    new SyncHelper().get(CreateOrderActivity.this,
            Connections.CURRENCIES(CreateOrderActivity.this),
            null, null, new SyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String data, int requestCode) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data);
                        if (object.getString("errors") == "false") {
                            JSONArray currenciesArray = object.getJSONObject("data")
                                    .getJSONArray("currencies");
                            for (int i=0; i< currenciesArray.length(); i++) {
                                String currencyRef = currenciesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ref");
                                String currencyId = currenciesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                                _currencies.put(currencyRef, currencyId);
                            }

                            String[] currencyrefs = Arrays.copyOf(_currencies.keySet().toArray(),
                                    _currencies.keySet().toArray().length, String[].class);
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                            new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,currencyrefs);
                            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then the spinner rendered view is all shrunk like so:

[image]

even though in both cases, we're using `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`.. any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue, for me the first example gives an output similar to the second example and second example gives the same output (No margins, height is set to wrap_content, also for the second example, I only used the same adapter constructor to simulate). The difference in behavior might be because of the different APIs (I used an emulator with API 26).

However, to me your first and desired output looks like `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` instead of `simple_spinner_item` and I was able to produce a similar spinner with `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`, so you might want to check it out.